# xcode crash when parsing xml?

Tags: xml, xcode, parsing

I am developing an application in which i am getting xml from web.But some xml files are very large so when i parse xml in simulator it crashes the xcode also? do someone knows how to resolve this issue? BTW i know how to use NSXML parser only.So if this isn't work for me then please tell a step by step guide to any other approach mentioned.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should first save your data in database before simulating it. As you know the memory management is very important in cocoa hence, this is the right approach.